# Passing Variables From Cs File to another Cs File in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to pass the m_paths value from the class : ExtractDescriptorsForm.Cs to VisualizeFrom.Cs .. 
This is how the variable is defined in ExtractDescriptorsForm.Cs :

```
namespace MediaLab.TopSurf
{
    public partial class ExtractDescriptorsForm : Form
        {
            // list of paths that point directly at images, or at
            // directories that contain images
            List<string> m_paths;
            public List<string> Paths { get { return m_paths; } }
     ......}}
```

What I wrote in VisualizeForm.Cs :

```
List<string> j = ExtractDescriptorsForm.m_paths;
```

The error is :

an object reference is required for the non-static field,method or property 'MediaLab.TopSurf.ExtractDescriptorsForm.m_paths'

Comment: You might perhaps develop a better understanding of the difference between a class and an instance of the class.  For example, a class might be `Person` and an instance of the class might be `Person joe = new Person()`.  The variable `joe` now holds a *reference* to an instance of the Person class.  Once you understand this distinction, the concept of *static* will make much more sense.

Comment: That variable isn't static, so you need an object reference. I assume you have a `var thing = new ExtractDescriptorsForm()` somewhere? To get to the variable in that case you would do `List<string> j = thing.m_paths;` edit: That's if you make it public. For the the code posted `List<string> j = thing.Paths;` should work.

Comment: Also variables are `private` by default which means even if you had an instance of the class you wouldn't be able to reference `m_paths`. You'd have to change it to `public` - but that opens up a whole new can of worms, but there's already a `public ` property you should be using.

Comment: Where shoud I add var thing = new ExtractDescriptorsForm() ? in which class??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, I need to make sure you understand something very fundamental here:

**Files have *nothing* to do with this!**

You're working with class *objects*, not files. You can have more than one `ExtractDescriptorsForm` showing the on the screen at the same time, and there's no reason this form needs to be in a file named `ExtractDescriptorsForm.cs`. In fact, you could put both the `ExtractDescriptorsForm` and the `VisualizeFrom` class definitions in the same file.

Learn this, and learn it well, or you'll struggle to ever be effective writing code.

Case in point... for this issue, the `VisualizeFrom` object is trying to look for the `Paths` property in a `ExtractDescriptorsForm` object... but which object? You're using class name here, when you need to be thinking about instances of the class.

I see the comments that you're trying to create a new `ExtractDescriptorsForm` object. This is probably a mistake. You very likely already have an instance in your program somewhere that you're already using, possibly created by code that Visual Studio provided for you. You need to find that existing reference.